# Why Keras SimpleRNN Layer implements output-to-output instead of hidden-to-hidden recurrence?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I've been checking the literature and the most common recurrence to be performed is hidden-to-hidden, i.e.:

```
h(t) = tanh(W_x*x(t)+b+W_hh*h(t-1))
output(t) = tanh(W_ho*h(t)+b)
```

However, in tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNN Layer it is implemented the output-to-output recurrence:

```
h(t) = W_xh*x(t)+b_h
output(t) = tanh(h(t)+W_oo*output(t-1)))
```

This can be demonstrated with the following code extracted from the book Python Machine Learning 3rd Ed:

```
rnn_layer = tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNN(
    units=2, use_bias=True,
    return_sequences=True)
rnn_layer.build(input_shape=(None, None, 5))

w_xh, w_oo, b_h = rnn_layer.weights

x_seq = tf.convert_to_tensor(
     [[1.0]*5, [2.0]*5, [3.0]*5],
     dtype=tf.float32)
 ## output of SimepleRNN:
 output = rnn_layer(tf.reshape(x_seq, shape=(1, 3, 5)))
 ## manually computing the output:
 out_man = []
 for t in range(len(x_seq)):
    xt = tf.reshape(x_seq[t], (1, 5))
    print('Time step {} =>'.format(t))
    print('   Input           :', xt.numpy())

    ht = tf.matmul(xt, w_xh) + b_h
    print('   Hidden          :', ht.numpy())
    if t>0:
    #Time step 0 =>
        prev_o = out_man[t-1]
    else:
        prev_o = tf.zeros(shape=(ht.shape))
    ot = ht + tf.matmul(prev_o, w_oo)
    ot = tf.math.tanh(ot)
    out_man.append(ot)
    print('   Output (manual) :', ot.numpy())
    print('   SimpleRNN output:'.format(t),
          output[0][t].numpy())
    print()
```

Why there's such a difference between the implementation and literature? Is output-to-output superior to hidden-to-hidden in practice?